# glm model fits Poisson distribution although values are continuous and contain NA and 0

Tags: r, glm, poisson, continuous

I have a dataset consisting of continuous values and some NA. I need to do a glm with this data and tried with the family = poison. It works, although I get an error message, and when I check the model with the check_model() function, the model seems to be a good fit. What does that mean? Can I use this model? What would you do?
Thanks a lot for your answers!

Comment: If it "works", you probably received a Warning, not an Error. What does the warning message say? Why are you using a Poisson family GLM on continuous data? I wouldn't do that. How good does the fit look? But with all those comments, this is much more of a statistical question than a programming question: it would be more at home at stats.stackexchange.

Comment: Welcome to SO! A few guidelines for asking questions here: (1) Keep each post/question to one question. Currently, you're asking about the meaning of the model, its usability, and what we would do, which are three different questions.  (2) SO questions should not be opinion-based - so what we would do and whether you "can" use it are not great questions for SO. (3) If you get an error, it's highly encouraged to provide example data and code that reproduces your issue. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). @GregorThomas is probably right and it's a warning.